# Update order by limit is giving me an error

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table using order by and limit. The reason is that I want to offset the first 3 entries. I started by making a query to list what I wanted to update, and that works.

```
SELECT `Name`,`active`
FROM `tlogon`
WHERE `active`>0 ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3,18446744073709551610
```

So I have 8 items in my table and it is showing the last 3 which is correct, because 2 of the rows have an active of zero. So then I tried to turn my select into an update like this.

```
UPDATE `tlogon` SET `active`=3
WHERE `active`>0 ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3,18446744073709551610
```

The idea here is that it gets a list of `active` and ignores the first 3, and then I only want to update after the first three. However the above code gives an error in phpmyadmin.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '18446744073709551610' at line 2
```

So my question is. Why does my select work, but my update query fail?

### EDIT

Ok I have tried something else, but again I have failed. My id is autoincrementing so I tried the following code

```
UPDATE `tlogon` SET `active`=3
Where `id`>=(
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `tlogon`
    WHERE `active`>0 ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3,1
)
```

Now it works in simulation, but the problem when I do it for real I get this error.

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'tlogon' for update in FROM clause
```

Which is annoying because what I am doing is getting the first id above my limit and changing them, but again I have failed.

So then I thought about a Right Join like this

```
UPDATE `tlogon` AS `a`
RIGHT JOIN `tlogon` AS `b` ON `a`.`id`>`b`.`id`
SET `a`.`active`=3
WHERE (
   SELECT `id`
    FROM `b`
    WHERE `tlogon`.`active`>0 ORDER BY `tlogon`.`id` LIMIT 3,1 
 )
```

But I think I am doing something wrong because now it is telling me that table b does not exist.

Comment: what is the meaning of the comma and the numbers after the comma?

Comment: @LelioFaieta when there are 2 values for `LIMIT` (separated by comma), the first one is the offset. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Comment: @axiac thanks for the info

Comment: Do you have a primary key?

Comment: Yes I have a primary key which is the id. The second value is probably the biggest value you can have in a database, basically unlimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have an answer, but it only works if you are using an auto incrementing id.

```
UPDATE `tlogon` AS `a`
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT `id`
    FROM `tlogon`
    WHERE `active`>0 ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 3,1) as b  ON `a`.`id` >= `b`.`id`
SET `a`.`active`=3
```

because you cannot reference the same table with the select I ended up using an inner join to the same table.

Basically I am getting the next highest id in my where clause and only changing active if the id is higher. Thus the first 3 entries will be ignored and the rest will be changed to 3, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement does not support an offset for `LIMIT`, only the number of rows to update.

Its syntax is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
   SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT},
    [, col_name={expr | DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

You need to find another way to ignore the first 3 rows.

Comment: I am holding out for a solution to the problem. If nobody can come up with a solution then I will give you a tick as you have answered my question. I am still a little stuck. I might have to use two queries unfortunately.